# Is it possible to completely hide a staff from the score?

Tags: finale

I have a score where 1 voice is doubled by 3 instruments (in different transpositions). I want to completely hide 2 of them from the score. This is usually done when the cello and contrabass are shown on the same staff with the latter sounding an octave low. I still want the parts in the file.

Finale offers to hide staves, but this only applies to the places where they don't play. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

1. Select the `Staff Tool`.
2. Open the `Edit Staff Attributes...` dialog.
3. Under `Behaviors`, select `Force hide staff: in Score Only (Collapse)`.
4. Click `OK`.